# beautifulsoup4 present in Anaconda3 package list but cannot use it

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
import beautifulsoup
import requests 
pageurl = "https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:TUMx+iLabx+2T2020/block-v1:TUMx+iLabx+2T2020+type@sequential+block@d7110bd0bcf4448eb3b170be28f7dfe4/block-v1:TUMx+iLabx+2T2020+type@vertical+block@141d0b4db33649b7bbffd7c4ec8a465c"
r = requests.get(pageurl)
soup = beautifulsoup(r.content,"html5lib")
links = soup.findALL("a")
```

I have Anaconda3 installed on my machine. When I do `pip list` in the cmd I can see beautifulsoup4 present there with other packages,but when I import it in spyder IDE it shows NoModuleFoundError. I have also tried `pip installing bs4` but it dosen't work.

Comment: You have to `python -m pip install beautifulsoup4` but `import bs4`. The name of the "_distribution package_" and the name of the "_import package_" do not match.

Comment: Please show your demo code.It will be helpful for ours.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're importing `bs4` and not `beautifulsoup4`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` instead of `import beautifulsoup` and You have to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html5lib")` instead of `soup = beautifulsoup(r.content,"html5lib")`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

pageurl = "https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:TUMx+iLabx+2T2020/block-v1:TUMx+iLabx+2T2020+type@sequential+block@d7110bd0bcf4448eb3b170be28f7dfe4/block-v1:TUMx+iLabx+2T2020+type@vertical+block@141d0b4db33649b7bbffd7c4ec8a465c"
r = requests.get(pageurl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html5lib")
```